# Loading image and resizing through canvas causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, canvas, onload

I want to get an image scaled correctly after loading it with a dummy click on a `<input type='file'>` and compressing it via drawing it onto a canvas. When calling a `console.log()` inside the `img.onload` I discovered it was being run in a loop. Putting the `img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")` outside of the onload results in a blank image but no loop. Moving things around by trial and error has not been effective as I don't get the dynamics at play here (even though I can get images redrawn when rescaling a canvas). Thanks!

```
$('button.picture').on('click',function(){
        var outerWrapper = $(this).closest('.outerWrapper')
        $(this).siblings('.imageLoad').on('change', function(e){
            var loadedImage = e.target.files[0]
            var img = new Image();
            img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(loadedImage);
            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            canvas.width = outerWrapper.width()
            canvas.height = outerWrapper.height()
            img.onload = function(e){
                //still here the img.width returns the canvas width and not the original image's width
                console.log(img.width)
                var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
                context.drawImage(img,0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height )
                img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
            }
      $(this).closest('.outerWrapper').children('.imageWrapper').append(img)
        })
    $(this).siblings('.imageLoad').trigger('click')
})
```

Comment: Inside your `img.onload` you set `img.src = `. That would cause infinite loop I would imagine.

Comment: It's true, it seems to, testing with it on the outside results in a blank image, though, so left the code that at least generates an image. Is an `img.onload` within an `img.onload` meant to be standard practice? I'll test that but it doesn't feel right...unless it is?

Comment: Inside your onload method you could set `img.onload = function(){}` before you update it with a new image source to prevent the infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question I want to make clear what my aims were:

1. Load in image through a dummy click on an `<input type="file">`
2. Keeps the aspect ratio of the original image
3. Compress it

What worked was not setting `img.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png")` as you would when resizing a canvas but by loading the original again image with `URL.createObjectURL(loadedImage)`. To preserve the aspect ration I had to create two separate images, one to get the `img.naturalWidth` and `img.naturalHeight` for calculation and the next to load the image onto the canvas. Works a charm. Would be interested to learn where it can be refined.

```
$('button.picture').on('click',function(){
    var outerWrapper = $(this).closest('.outerWrapper')

    $(this).siblings('.imageLoad').on('change', function(e){

        var loadedImage = e.target.files[0]
        var img = new Image();
        img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(loadedImage);

        var canvasPic = $('<canvas class="canvasPic"></canvas>')
        canvasPic.prependTo(outerWrapper)

        var canvas = canvasPic[0]
        canvas.width = outerWrapper.width()
        canvas.height = outerWrapper.height()
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        var image = new Image();
        image.onload = function(){
            var w = img.naturalWidth
            var h = img.naturalHeight
            var ratio = h/w
            var newWidth = canvas.height/ratio
            context.drawImage(img,0,0,newWidth,canvas.height)
        }
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(loadedImage);
    })
    $(this).siblings('.imageLoad').trigger('click')
})
```